# Linux How to List Files greater than particular timestamp in file name?

Tags: linux, date, unix, datetime, timestamp

I have a directory in **linux** which has a list of log files where log files get auto generated if some job runs. Each log file gets appended with the timestamp like "**JobName_TimeStamp**"

**UPDATED:**

```
job_2014-05-28_15:05:26.log
job_2014-05-28_15:06:58.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:02.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:57.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log

job1_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

I wanted to run a linux command to list all files greater than a particular timestamp?

**For Example 1** : I will pass two parameters , If the **TimeStamp** given is "**2014-05-28_15:08:00**" and **Job Name** is "**job**"

I should get the list as

```
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

**Example 2** : I will pass two parameters , If the **TimeStamp** given is "`2014-05-28_15:08:11`" and **Job Name** is "**job1**"

I should get the list as

```
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple bash script and get your output

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern1=`echo $1 | sed  's/_/ /'`;
pattern2=`date -d "$pattern1" "+%s"`
for file in `ls *.log` 
do
    job=`echo "$file" |  sed -r 's/([^_]+).*/\1/g'`
    time=`echo "$file" | sed -r 's/([^_]+_)(.*)_(.*)\..*/\2 \3/g'`
    pattern3=`date -d "$time" "+%s"`
            if [ $2 == $job ]  && [ $pattern3 -gt $pattern2 ] ; then 
                    echo  "$file" 
            fi
done
```

You have to run this method

```
 $bash script_file.sh <timestamp> <job>
```

Like

```
$bash script_file.sh 2014-05-28_15:08:00 job
```

Instead of pattern1=`echo $1 | sed 's/_/ /'`

You put the below line in that location.

```
job1=`echo $1 | sed -r 's/([^_]+).*/\1/g'`;
pattern1=`echo $1 | sed -r 's/([^_]+_)(.*)_(.*)\..*/\2 \3/g'`
```

and Instead of $2 on if statement you need to put the $job1.

Comment: A small change can u make in the above script. If my full job name is
job.27-05-14_18.36.49.out how to change the above regex pattern ?

Comment: Are you going to pass single argument like job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log this format and get the same result?

Comment: `arg1=\`echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([^_]+).*/\1/g'\`` you will get the job and `arg2=\`echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([^_]+_)(.*)_(.*)\..*/\2 \3/g'\`` and you get the time stamp in separate variable .arg1 contain job name and arg2 contain timestamps .SO based on you have to re execute the above code .

Comment: Yes thanks i will check it . What is meant is that in my log file directory if have file format like "job.27-05-14_18.36.49.out" your updated answer should work right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54765/discussion-between-kalanidhi-m-and-kabilan).

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the name can do the job:

```
ls | sort | awk '{if ($0 > "job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log") {print}}'
```

`sort` may not be needed but I put it here to make sure the names are sorted by alphabet order.

**Edit:**

The commands above does not work for file names with different prefix or suffix. But if you can make sure 1. no space in file names 2. the date format part is the same. you can write code like this:

```
ls | sort \
   | sed 's/\(^.*$\)/& &/' \
   | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\).* \(.*\)/\1 \2/' \
   | awk '{if ($1 > "2014-05-28_15:08:00") {print $2}}'
```

It looks dirty and cannot be the best one, but should work. You can write you own base on this idea.

Comment: Yes this works :) . Will it work even if the job names are differant ? because i will be passing the job name and the timestamp for comparison

Comment: No, it doesn't work for file names with different prefix or suffix directly. Let's write more about this by editing this answer.